# .NET MVC 5 update application state regarding user interactions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all I am frontend developer, I am developing an .NET MVC 5 web application using C#, I would like to know and understand how to do next:

I got a table of users:

dbo.Users

```
Id  |  Name  |  Age
------------------
1   |  John  |  28
2   |  James |  31
3   |  Mary  |  25
```

This is my UI, a list with all users from dbo.Users but I will have a filter, at the bottom bar with a button for each user Id, so on clicking in 1 it will filter the list to show just user with Id 1. Also I would like to track current user Id in some model.

So in this context I can have a ViewModel which I am passing currentUserId, Users and UserBarSwitcher

```
Id    Name    Age
1     John    28
2     James   31
3     Mary    25

  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Click in 1

```
Id    Name    Age
1     John    28

  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

What I want to achieve is:

- On click at the User Id bar, update model for currentUSerId to the Id selected
- Mark this button as selected (with a class for example)
- Filter the list of users to show just the one with the Id I pressed on the bar.

I am not looking for code resolution, I want to understand the process, how it works in order to update application state regarding user interactions.

Thank you for your help.